# Сценарии/скрипты для работы в браузере

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, плагин

Всем доброго дня!

Стоит задача: написать несколько скриптов/макросов для ускорения работы контент-редакторов сайта. Задачи на уровне "найти нужное место на странице, вставить текст/ссылку, выполнить действие сохранить". Скрипты должны выполняться последовательно (сценарии), в 3-5 шагов при заданных условиях (в небольшой форме): переключение в режим редактирования, выбор нужной вкладки, поиск нужного места/фрагмента, вставка значения, сохранение.

Выполнение сценариев строго на стороне клиента (javascript) без правок движка сайта, касаний mysql и тд, по сути, речь о "простой" эмуляции действий пользователя в браузере.

Оптимально хотели бы сделать плагин для браузера Chrome, т.к. скрипты работают по вводным значениям, то есть, нужна по крайней мере форма для ввода данных.

В целом задача довольно узкая: внесение заданного значения (текст, ссылка) в нужное место в открытом документе.

Подскажите пожалуйста, чем и как реализовать?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что это не фриланс.

Comment: Обращение не по адресу. Здесь не фриланс-сайт. Если у вас есть опыт программирования, то вы найдете большую часть ответа через поиск, если нет, обращайтесь на биржу фриланса или форумы программистов.

Comment: Ну и чего вы за одну лишнюю фразу про "договориться" хотите закрыть вполне нормальный вопрос?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Эта ключевая фраза, которая говорит что автор сам ничего не хочет/не может сделать для решения проблемы. В таком случае ему тут не место.

Comment: @TheDoctor, в любом случае, вопрос хороший, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Чем же? Делать за кого-то работу?

Comment: @TheDoctor, для того, чтобы сделать за кого-то работу, в вопросе банально недостаточно данных. А вот для того, чтобы рассказать, как подобное делается - вполне достаточно. Подробнее высказался на http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/239/178988

Comment: @Евгений, вопросы с предложениями о работе(даже косвенные) оставляйте на других специализированных сайтах. Вопрос отредактирован по правилам форума, дабы закрыть бессмысленный спор в комментариях.

Comment: @Qwertiy Большое спасибо, что показали куда смотреть, реально не имел понятия с чего подступиться :)
Размышлял вокруг DOM, консоли Chrome, и тд, но все туманно и не определенно.
Может подскажете, где собрать больше инфы по вопросу? Заранее спасибо.

п.с. тут выше комментарии про "ищите на форумах", "фриланс в помощь". Но, фриланс не может помочь, а форумы подскажите плиз, а то и так понятно, что "ищите на форумах" Ваш Кэп (с)

Answer (score 2):

> Подскажите пожалуйста, чем и как реализовать?

В плагине нет необходимости, достаточно обычного расширения. Расширения для браузера реализуются на js.

Пишешь в файле манифеста запрос на доступ к нужному сайту, подключаешь скрипт, который добавляет page action, на которую повешен обработчик, выполняющий необходимые действия.

Возможно, придётся запросить доступ ещё и на `tabs`.